# Cancel a Drag & Drop for some specific items in a Gtk.TreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have a `Gtk.TreeView` here. Most but not all of the items should be able to be dragged & dropped. In this example the first item should **not** be able to be dragged & dropped but it should be selectable.

How can I realize this? Maybe I have to use the `drag-begin` signal and stop the drag in there. But I don't know how.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="TreeView Drag and Drop")
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # "model" with dummy data
        self.store = Gtk.TreeStore(str)
        self.store.append(None, ['do not drag this'])
        self.store.append(None, ['drag this'])
        self.view = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.store)
        self.add(self.view)

        # build columsn
        colA = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Col A', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0)
        self.view.append_column(colA)

        # DnD events
        self.view.connect("drag-data-received", self.drag_data_received)
        self.view.connect("drag-data-get", self.drag_data_get)
        self.view.connect("drag-begin", self.drag_begin)

        target_entry = Gtk.TargetEntry.new('text/plain', 2, 0)
        self.view.enable_model_drag_source(
                Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK,[target_entry], 
                Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT|Gdk.DragAction.MOVE
        )
        self.view.enable_model_drag_dest(
                [target_entry],
                Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT|Gdk.DragAction.MOVE
        )

    def drag_data_get (self, treeview, drag_context, data, info, time):
        model, path = treeview.get_selection().get_selected_rows()
        print('dd-get\tpath: {}'.format(path))
        data.set_text(str(path[0]), -1)

    def drag_data_received (self, treeview, drag_context, x,y, data,info, time):
        print('dd-received')
        store = treeview.get_model()
        source_iter = store.get_iter(data.get_text())
        dest_path, drop_pos = self.view.get_dest_row_at_pos(x, y)
        print('path: {} pos: {}'.format(dest_path, drop_pos))

    def drag_begin(self, widget, context):
        print(widget)
        print(context)

win = MainWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to overload [`Gtk.TreeDragSource.do_row_draggable()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeDragSource.html#Gtk.TreeDragSource.do_row_draggable).

```
class MyTreeStore (Gtk.TreeStore):
    # ...
    def do_row_draggable(self, path):
        # do your decision here

        return True # draggable
        return False # NOT draggable
```