# Does GTK TreeView have a way to cancel drag-and-drop within the "drag begin" event?

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

I have searched the web and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974845/cancel-a-drag-drop-for-some-specific-items-in-a-gtk-treeview), but the answer was disabling drag and drop in the first place. But I want to cancel the drag-and-drop after it has started within the "drag begin" event, without releasing the mouse button. Is that possible?

The reason why I am trying to do is that, I am using GTK on Windows, and drag-and-drop does not work on Windows. If I try to drag an item of a TreeView, my GTK app starts acting like it is doing drag-and-drop, changing the mouse pointer to a hand, but dropping on other native Windows applications has no effect. So, my idea is that once drag-and-drop has started by dragging an item of a TreeView, and I get the "drag begin" event (mouse button has not been released), I cancel GTK's drag-and-drop and call Windows' native drag-and-drop.